# Wait for ApplicationRoute to resolve before going to a child route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

To explain the issue I'm facing, I have 2 routes : `ApplicationRoute` and `SomeRoute`. I would need to wait for `ApplicationRoute` to resolve *before* trying to do something with `SomeRoute`.

The call order I see in debug :

```
ApplicationRoute.model // which returns a promise
SomeRoute.model
SomeRoute.setupController
ApplicationRoute.setupController
```

What I would want :

```
ApplicationRoute.model // which returns a promise
ApplicationRoute.setupController
SomeRoute.model
SomeRoute.setupController
```

There's probably a detail I'm missing somewhere...

**UPDATE**

The reason I incist for the `ApplicationRoute.setupController` to be able before other routes is that I use this to initialize some others controllers.

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return Ember.$.getJSON("api/settings");
    },
    setupController: function(controller, jsonSettings) {
        this.store.pushPayload(jsonSettings);

        this.controllerFor("foobar").set("content", this.store.all("foobar"));
        this.controllerFor("foobaz").set("content", this.store.all("foobaz"));
        this.controllerFor("foobam").set("content", this.store.all("foobam"));
    }
});
```

Comment: In that case, consider putting your `setupController` logic in an `afterModel` hook instead. Logically, what you are doing in `setupController` is not setting up the controller; it's manipulating and processing the model, and therefore rightfully belongs in one of the model hooks.

Comment: Test is green ! Thank you so much. Could you add your comment in your response so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a transition to proceed, all models in the hierarchy must resolve. That's as it should be; we don't want to start doing application logic--which includes things that might be done in a `setupController`, at whatever level of the hierarchy--while the necessary models are still pending and the transition has not been finalized and might even still be aborted.

So if we agree that models are resolved in top-down order, which makes sense--after all, a child route's `model` hook might want to refer to `this.modelFor('parent')`--why is `setupController` called in reverse order, from the bottom up? I'm guessing there may be good reasons for this, including the rendering lifecycle, but in one important sense it doesn't really matter: a parent route's controller being set up properly is not a prerequisite for the child route's controller to be set up. The parent route's controller is not even directly accessible from the child route's controller unless you inject it. For more on this topic, see http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/why-is-setupcontroller-called-after-the-model-hook-of-nested-routes/2655/9.

As an aside, you use the expression "a route resolving", and seem to imply that calling `setupController` is a part of that resolution process, but it would be more correct to refer to "a route's **model** resolving", and that does not include the invocation of `setupController`, which is something that happens  **after** all the models in the chain of routes have resolved and the transition finalized.

In the specific case shown in the update to your question, consider putting your `setupController` logic in an `afterModel` hook instead. Logically, what you are doing in `setupController` is not setting up the controller; it's manipulating and processing the model, and therefore rightfully belongs in one of the model hooks.